# HTML5 canvas - text on rotated rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to place text on sqlare rotated 45 degrees. The problem is my text is under the rectangle shape. Can I change position of text?

my code is like

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var square= c.getContext("2d");
var text= c.getContext("2d");

text.fillStyle = "red";
text.fillText("1", 40, 50);
text.fillStyle = "#000000";

square.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
square.fillRect(50, 0, 50, 50);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awmhhn6z/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing the text first, then the rectangle, and then wondering why the text is behind the rectangle?

Firstly, you only need to `getContext` once, not twice.

Second, draw things in the right order: background first, then foreground.

Comment: if I place rectangle before text I'm getting my text rotated. Is it possible to prevent text rotation? https://jsfiddle.net/awmhhn6z/5/

Comment: Save and restore the context, like you're supposed to :p https://jsfiddle.net/awmhhn6z/6/

Answer (score 1):

It appears you may have a misconception about how the *canvas context* works.

You see, you only need one instance of the *context*, which you can then use to create all your shapes, paths and even write text on the canvas.

Also, you are drawing the text before the rectangle, which would cover it up.

With that in mind, I've created a new [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6hdsgu1g/) where you can check out a correct approach to do this.

### HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
```

### JavaScript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); //we get the canvas context

ctx.save(); //save context properties

ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 4);
ctx.fillRect(50, 0, 50, 50);

ctx.restore(); //restore saved properties

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillText("1", 40, 50);
```

As you can see, we only take one instance of the context, and we draw from there.

The context `save()` and `restore()` functions help prevent the rotation from affecting the text. You could also rotate the same amount in the opposite direction.

Hope it helps!